# How to add python source code to libreoffice writer?

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I'm using a libreoffice on Linux and I use Manjaro distribution. I need to add my python code to the libreoffice writer because I cannot add code highlighter -> https://github.com/slgobinath/libreoffice-code-highlighter
Since there is not package for arch.

What is the best way for me to add my python source code to libreoffice writer?

Comment: "Since there is not package for arch." Do you mean that the extension does not work on your system, or are you saying that there seems to be no script provider package that enables python macros, such as `libreoffice-script-provider-python`?

Comment: Do you want to extend Writer capabilities using a macro written in Python, or do you want to insert, and properly highlight, a short piece of Python code inside a Writer document?

Answer (score 0):

Python macros can be created with a text editor.  [The APSO extension](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python) provides a convenient way to do this.

To get started writing python code for LibreOffice, see [this tutorial](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html).

To modify the code highlighter extension linked in your question so that it works on your system, unzip the `.oxt` file, make changes with a text editor, zip it back up and then install the changed version in LibreOffice.